# How to implement more than one jQuery scrollable tabs control?

Tags: jquery, tabs, scrollable

I have successfully incorporated this scrollable tab control to my website:
http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-slider.html

I would like to use this at the top of the page, and once again in the middle of the page.  However, this solution seems to only allow one instance of it per page.

How do I use it in multiple places on a single page?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Niall Doherty has a great solution that allows multiple jQuery tab controls here:
http://www.ndoherty.biz/tag/coda-slider/